# Regular Expression - Match all but first letter in each word in sentence

Tags: regex, lookbehind, regex-lookarounds

I've almost got the answer here, but I'm missing something and I hope someone here can help me out.

I need a regular expression that will match all but the first letter in each word in a sentence. Then I need to replace the matched letters with the correct number of asterisks. For example, if I have the following sentence:

```
There is an enormous apple tree in my backyard.
```

I need to get this result:

```
T**** i* a* e******* a**** t*** i* m* b*******.
```

I have managed to come up with an expression that almost does that:

```
(?<=(\b[A-Za-z]))([a-z]+)
```

Using the example sentence above, that expression gives me:

```
T* i* a* e* a* t* i* m* b*.
```

How do I get the right number of asterisks?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to use regular expressions for any particular reason? Depending on the programming language you're writing in, you can use a substring with replacement to get the same effect

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
\B[a-z]
```

`\B` is the opposite of `\b` - it matches where there is no word boundary - when we see a letter that is after another letter.

Your regex is replacing the whole tail of the word - `[a-z]+`, with a single asterisks. You should replace them one by one. If you want it to work, you should match a single letter, but check is has a word behind it (which is a little pointless, since you might as well check for a single letter `(?<=[A-Za-z])[a-z]`):

```
(?<=\b[A-Za-z]+)[a-z]
```

(note that the last regex has a variable length lookbehind, which isn't implemented in most regex flavors)

Comment: The shortest regex here is probably `\B\w`, but `\w` adds upper case letters and underscores.

Comment: `(?<=\b[A-Za-z]+)` won't work in any flavor but .NET and JGSoft.  You had it right the first time.

Comment: @Alan - good point. I've added a warning on that. Either way, I did say it was rather pointless `:)`

Comment: And (depending on the regex flavor and whether you're planning on matching other characters than unaccented letters between a and z) you might want to use `\p{L}` or `[^\W\d_]` instead of `[a-z]`.

Comment: How would that work when you had something like "Jack's toothbrush"?

Comment: @NathanArthur - That is a good question... The underlying question is even more difficult: What is a word? The pattern above assumes a word is made of alphanumeric characters, which is wrong. In fact, I do not believe I can solve that problem reliably with a simple pattern - there are just too many edge cases. Still, as for your question: In .Net, you can add an apostrophe to the pattern above: `(?<=\b[A-Za-z']+)[a-z]`. On other flavors I think `(?<=\B|\b')[a-z]` can work. Either way, it requires some thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
\B\w
```

this will replace all characters except for the first letter of every word

from this `==Hello==World==` into `==H****==W****==`

Answer (score 0):

Try this possibly:

```
(\w{1})\w*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question.  Adding an answer since the others don't seem to solve this problem completely or clearly.  The simplest regular expression that handles this is `/(\B[a-z])/g`. This adds 'g' as a global flag, so the single character search will be repeated throughout the string.

```
string = "There is an enormous apple tree in my backyard."
answer = string.replace(/\B[a-z]/g, "*");
```

```js
string = "There is an enormous apple tree in my backyard."
$("#stringDiv").text(string);

answer = string.replace(/\B[a-z]/g, "*");
$("#answerDiv").text(answer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stringDiv"></div>
<div id="answerDiv"></div>
```