# Regular expression to select entire word except first letter, including words such as "Jack's" and "merry-go-round"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to select all of each word except the first character, [much as @mahdaeng wanted to do here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790375/regular-expression-match-all-but-first-letter-in-each-word-in-sentence). The solution offered to his question was to use `\B[a-z]`. This works fine, except when a word contains some form of punctuation, such as "Jack's" and "merry-go-round". Is there a way to select the entire word including any contained punctuation? (Not including outside punctuation such as "? , ." etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can enumerate the acceptable in-word punctuation, you could just expand upon the answer you linked:

```
\B[a-zA-Z'-]+
```

Answer (score 3):

A regex really isn't necessary here, since you can just `split` your word on spaces and deal with each word accordingly.  Since you don't mention an underlying language, here's an implementation in Perl:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$_="Jack's merry-go-round revolves way too fast!";
my @words=split /\s+/;
foreach my $word(@words)
{
  my $stripped_word=substr($word,1);
  $stripped_word=~s/[^a-z]$//i; #stripping out end punctuation
  print "$stripped_word\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
ack's
erry-go-round
evolves
ay
oo
ast
```

Comment: Great approach! Sadly, I'm actually using InDesign grep styles, so can't really use this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
\B[^\s]+
```

(where `^\s` means "not whitespace") should get you what you want assuming the words are whitespace-delimited. If they're also punctuation-delimited, you might need to enumerate the punctuation:

```
\B[^\s,.?!]+
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome! I'll have to remember this method. In my case, however, I think it would probably stay less hairy to delineate what is allowed instead of what isn't.